# Ruby on Rails migration, two primary keys but just one auto-incremented

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building a RoR multi-tenant application. So the application database could be hosted on diverse places and could be split or re-merged. That's why I need a couple of primary keys: a classic auto-incremented id and another one which is the foreign key of my main model (which couldn't be divise).

I want to do something like this:

```
create_table :table_name do |t|
  t.primary_key :id
  t.primary_key :second_id, :auto_increment => false
  # ...
  t.timestamps
end
```

But I don't find the right syntax, any idea?

***Edit** : I want to do it with a migration!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of researches and tests, I think it's impossible to do it with a classic migration. But I find the solution to continue to manage my database with migrations. It's possible to include pieces of SQL with the `execute` command.

So, my creation look like that :

```
def self.up

  execute "CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `org_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `org_id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=151 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;"

end

def self.down
  drop_table :table_name
end
```

It's not really pretty but it do the job.

Comment: Then you lose the ability to fetch id's using rails' `find` method

Comment: @Anwar why ? It just creates a classic MySQL table with auto-incremented id.

Comment: I've tested it today. Dual columned table loses rails' `find_by_id` methods and also `find` doesn't work as expected

Comment: This worked in 2011... I don't know what could happen with newer versions of Rails but I'm pretty sure that Active Record doesn't check your schema structure before a request. Your primary key structure should have no impact on `find`. Of course, if you want to find an object by its two ids, you have to create a new method that accept two arguments, Rails can't magically detect your table structure.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have two Primary keys on a table.

You can have two Candidate Keys (Called a Key in MySQL Unique indexes/constraints in other DBs)

You can have a composite primary key made up of two fields if you'd like. I think this is the syntax in mySQL `primary key (fieldA,fieldB)`

However it makes little sense to do a composite key when one of the fields is an autoincrement. Since the autoincrement alreayd make a unique by itself and every attribute other than then `id` would have a functional dependency on it. Including second_id in the primary key won't help you any.

Comment: Of course, I wanted to say a composite primary key. The problem is the same. **I know how to do this in MySQL but not with a RoR migration.**

Comment: I have seen this gem but, if it's possible, I would prefer manage this by myself because the gem do much things that I need.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE  `test`.`tst` (

`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,

`second_id` INT NOT NULL ,

`timest` DATE NOT NULL ,

UNIQUE (
`second_id`
)

) ENGINE = MYISAM ;

is this it?

Comment: Not right because second_id is also a foreign key, not unique. **And I want to do this with a RoR migration.**